# Changing activity crashes

Tags: java, android

My app crashes when I try to navigate to another activity. Why does that happen? 
I'm able to start the other activity when I launch it at first so there's no problem in the CheckUsernameActivity.

```
public class CheckNumberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText phoneNumberEditText;
    Button countryCodeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_number);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countryCodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countryCodeButton);
                phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberEditText);

                Log.v("areaCode", countryCodeButton.getText().toString());
                Log.v("phoneNumber", phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString());

                Intent k = new Intent(CheckNumberActivity.this, CheckUsernameActivity.class);
                startActivity(k);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your crash logs.  Have you registered CheckNumberActivity activity in Manifest ?

Comment: `Changing activity crashes` add crash logs with post

Comment: are you getting areaCode and phoneNumber in your log. Can you please post logcat

Comment: Have you declared `CheckUsernameActivity` in your manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have my new activity defined in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dimsumdev.runk" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".activity.CheckNumberActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.CheckUsernameActivity" >
            <!--Default Intent Filter-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.HomeActivity" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This way. I think it will help you.

```
public class CheckNumberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText phoneNumberEditText;
    Button countryCodeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_number);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        countryCodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countryCodeButton);
        phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberEditText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("areaCode", countryCodeButton.getText().toString());
                Log.v("phoneNumber", phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString());

                Intent k = new Intent(CheckNumberActivity.this, CheckUsernameActivity.class);
                startActivity(k);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if this seems to be the problem why he's able to move to other activity at first launch.

Comment: Because when you click on button it crashes there to find value at run time.I have removed find value from listener so you will not get any error now i hope

Comment: Please rum it this way. If you get any error let me know with logcat